# no content in ngrepeat even though html elements present

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting list of numbers from API and im using ng-repeat to display on the web page. For 10 number 10 elements are created but content is empty. I've tried many different combinations but content doesnt display.
HTML element looks like this[image]

As show im using button for ngrepeat but the text is missing.

Code:

```
    $scope.getParts = function(){
$http({
    method:"GET",
    url:'v1/getpartsname'
}).then(function(res){
    $scope.parts = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        $scope.parts.push(parseInt(res.data[i][0].trim()));
    }
   // $scope.partNumbers = parts;
    $scope.searchPart = "";
});
}
```

And the html is

```
<div className="container" ng-show="showPartNumbers" ng-init="getParts()">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="part in parts| filter:searchPart">
                <button type="button" ng-click="home(part)">{{part}}</button>                   
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I get the html displayed as following:

[image]

The formatted json which i bind with scope is:

[image]

The original json which i get from http call is :

[image]

Comment: did you verify `parseInt(res.data[i][0].trim())` has a value?

Comment: yes it contains all the integers @Ronnie

Comment: is `showPartNumbers` set? You have it in `ng-show`..I bet it's that. Your code looks fine otherwise

Comment: yes its set @Ronnie

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bv2mx9m0/ works just fine..you must have something else going on

Comment: yes thats the problem. I dont know what the error is @Ronnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SangitDhanani of course the plunker works, because you have removed the bit that's broken. One way to do this is save the json that you get back from your API call to a json file, and then you can put this in your plunker.

It will make the plunker closer to your problem, and hopefully help us to find the source.

A thing I have seen a few times is where a REST API returns JSON, but not as JSON, but stringified, needing a JSON.parse to unpack it. Something like

```
response: '{"id":"1234","name":"Mikkel"...
```

At first glance it looks like JSON, but in fact it's a string.

Comment: i used the same array as plunker and still am not able to display content in angular. I think there should be problem with my localhost. Im using django and rendering the html as :: return render(request, "index.html")

Comment: i was able to solve the problem. I used your suggestion for json and used verbatim which stops the django template engine from rendering.

Comment: Woo hoo! great result!

Answer (score 0):

parseInt might be failing (one of the values is blank/invalid?), try with just plain values ie no parseInt or trim:

```
$scope.parts.push(res.data[i]);
```

You can also try to put the data into a scope variable

```
$scope.rawData = res.data;
```

and then show that in the UI with

```
{{rawData | json}}
```

Although you can look at the data in the inspector to make sure of the structure

Comment: ive tried all the combinations. See updated question @Mikkel

Comment: So the set of buttons tells us you are receiving an array of data, but the blank buttons tells us that you are not pulling out the numbers correctly. Can you add the json to your question so I can see it please?

Comment: I changed my answer to refer to the data correctly - you didn't need the [0] as its just a plain array

Comment: The json i uploaded is the one which i format and bind with angular. I updated the original json which i get from http call.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you start your loop from 1 (it should be 0), there is nothing wrong with your code - it must be something else, can you put it in a plunker?

Comment: the strange part is that it works on plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/c5FmWU35BQWrXHGT2GvH?p=preview. I am using django rest framework and certainly im getting response from my models. I dont know what the problem is.